# Memory leak in MPI_Comm_free?

Tags: memory-leaks, mpi

I am very new to mpi, so sorry if the following is basic.

The following code appears to have a memory leak even when I run it with only one mpi task. The memory usage steadily grows until it consumes all the memory.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_init(&argc, &argv);

  while(1) {
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm);
    MPI_Comm_free(&comm);
  }
  
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

I also tested putting in barriers like the following:

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  MPI_init(&argc, &argv);

  while(1) {
    MPI_Comm comm;
    MPI_Comm_dup(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &comm);
    MPI_Barrier(comm);
    MPI_Comm_free(&comm);
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
  
  MPI_Finalize();
}
```

which did not slow the memory growth.

Comment: If the leak is confirmed, it is specific to a MPI library (vendor & version). Which MPI library are you using?

Comment: The following is what I get from MPI_Get_library_version: Open MPI v2.1.1, package: Open MPI buildd@lcy01-amd64-009 Distribution, ident: 2.1.1, repo rev: v2.1.0-100-ga2fdb5b, May 10, 2017. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I once tested  communicator duplication. Spectrum MPI is really bad, all the others I tried can created millions without a problem.

Comment: This is a very old version of Open MPI. Can you give a try to a supported version (ideally 4.1.2, but 4.0.7 is still supported)?

Comment: I am on ubuntu 18, and the apt-get installer only went as far as v2.1.1. I installed openmpi using conda instead. It now works fine. Just for completeness, the MPI_Get_library_version now gives: Open MPI v4.1.2, package: Open MPI conda@828eb7fae222 Distribution, ident: 4.1.2, repo rev: v4.1.2, Nov 24, 2021. Thank you @Gilles Gouaillardet!

Comment: And I believe Spectrum MPI is based on OpenMPI, so we found the same thing.